# Как подружить $.getScript() с асинхронным запросом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, асинхронность

Есть массив, который при некотором условии должен подгружаться извне. Есть необходимость в конце вызвать getScript(), в котором этот массив должен использоваться. В основном коде всё работает, массив определяется; в getScript() уже нет. В чём тут проблема и как её решить малой кровью?

```
(async function() {
  var test = [1,2,3]; var a = 0;
  if (a === 0) {
     let response = await fetch('/array.json');
     test = await response.json();
  }
  // тут код, всё нормально
  $.getScript('/script2.js');   // а тут test is not defined
})();
```

В `/script2.js`:

```
alert(test[0]);
```

Comment: скорее всего, для script2 массив должен быть глобальным, так что window.test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getScript` же тоже асинхронный, надо либо так:

```
$.getScript('/script2.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

  // вызываем функцию из script2.js, передаем ей массив test 
  some_function_from_script2(test);
   
});
```

, либо массив test должен быть глобально объявлен.